# Does GetKeyState() detect if the key is being released?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input, keyboard

Is there a way to detect if the key is being released using `GetKeyState()`? I read about it, and it only has 2 states, Toggled **0x8000** and Pressed **0x01**.

I want something like this:

```cpp
short Input(int Key, int Mode)
{
   if (Mode == KEY_RELEASE)
      if (GetKeyState(Key) & KEY_PRESS)
         //Wait for the key to be released
      else
         return GetKeyState(Key) & KEY_PRESS;
}
```

Comment: No. The only way to detect a key `release` using this function is to cache key value. If key was pressed last time you checked and now it isn't, it got released. Consider looking into other ways of handlling input.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to detect key releases using GetKeyState function but it doesn't have a release state.

Comment: He meant in the big picture, why do you need to know when a key has been released? Do you only care about your own window or all processes on the system etc.

Comment: @Anders I want to know if the key is being released because I'm making an input system for a Framework I'm working on, I care about my window only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetKeyState` returns information about the key state of the current input queue (your thread and attached threads). You can get similar information for all the keys with `GetKeyboardState`.

Those two functions should only be used in response to some event, you should not be polling over and over to detect changes.

The best way to detect keyboard changes in windows you control is to handle WM_KEYDOWN/UP and WM_CHAR messages.

Worst case scenario, use `SetWindowsHookEx` to catch keyboard events or window messages.